# Javascript architecture: break up modules or don't use modules at all

Tags: javascript, architecture

I'm in the middle of development and am running into architecture issues. I have boiled it down to the following options and can't decide which is best. Perhaps (most likely) there's an entirely different better solution and my problem will help others with their future architectural plans.

---

V1 ------------------

usersModule - fns: private A B C

adminModule - fns: private X Y but also C (same fn as in usersModule)

Compiled into users.js (usersModule only) and admin.js (adminModule only)

V2 ------------------

usersModule - fns: private A B, public C

adminModule - fns: private X Y and grabs usersModule.C

Compiled into main.js (with both usersModule and adminModule)

V3 ------------------

shareModule - fns: public C

usersModule - fns: private A B and grabs shareModule.C

adminModule - fns: private X Y and grabs shareModule.C

Compiled into users.js and admin.js (usersModule with sharedModule into users.js and adminModlue with sharedModlue into admin.js)

---

V1 offers the smallest file sizes, but is out: don't write the same fn-C twice.

V2 compiles to the largest file size as both usersModule and adminModule are compiled into one main.js. Only fn-C is needed by adminModule so it's a waste to compile in all of usersModule. And if a user logs in, then none of the adminModule code is needed. An even bigger waste!

V3 offers minimal file sizes with only the required code and seems the clear choice ... but ... now add this:

login.php passes html headers which loads admin.js or users.js. It also loads data to the js global space: userInfoJson and adminInfoJson.

usersModule parses userInfoJson and adminInfoJson into private usableInfo1 and usableInfo2 (some of which is used by fn-C). Similarly adminModule parses adminInfoJson into privately usable vars.

Sticking with V3, if admin logs in, then userInfoJson is never parsed into usableInfo1 and usableInfo2 (because userModule is never compiled into admin.js) and now fn-C (from sharedModule.C) doesn't work.

So V3 is out? Or do we add code to sharedModule that parses both userInfoJson and adminInfoJson into public vars? Or is V2 really the better choice? Or is there an altogether better way?

Comment: I don't understand the concept of private when it comes to _JavaScript_. Are any of A, B, C, X, Y dependent on eachother? Is there a problem with `adminModule` being applied over the top of (after) `userModule`?

Comment: @PaulS. - See [Mastering the Module Pattern](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern) and also [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)

Comment: @PaulS. - [Succinct explanation of the Revealing Modular Pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern)

Comment: No I understand closures and IIFEs etc, I was meaning to say "you can't trust the client", even under a closure the client can set breakpoints etc and access anything they want, or even just swap out the whole script for a modified file. I find the classical use of the word private to be misleading when you're talking about a language like JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving all shared methods to the lib module. (BTW I'm using revealing modules.)

Grunt then concats lib with user for the userMain.js and lib with admin for the adminMain.js.

This technique is working great so far.